# Filter List : Begin by... Android Studio

Tags: java, android, regex, list, filter

I would like to filter my List in order to get only the href's URL.
In my List, we can have multiple objects, so I would like to create another List, with only href's URL.

Here is a example return from my List :

```
[<a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery-113]" href='http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/11149460_10152656389992000_7842452340110509403_n.jpg'>]
```

I would like to obtain : http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/11149460_10152656389992000_7842452340110509403_n.jpg

So maybe create something like predicate or regex : Begin with **"href"**, and create a loop for adding in a new List when match is found ?

Cheers!...

My new code :

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<a rel=\"prettyPhoto\\[gallery-113\\]\"[^>]*>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(contentString);
List<String> urlWithRel=new ArrayList<String>();
String lastString;
while(matcher.find()) {
    urlWithRel.add(matcher.group());
    lastString = urlWithRel.toString();
    Pattern lastPattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=href=).*(?=>)");
    Matcher lastMatcher = lastPattern.matcher(lastString);
    List<String> imagesUrl=new ArrayList<String>();
    while(lastMatcher.find()) {
        imagesUrl.add(lastMatcher.group());
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "dernier : "+ imagesUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex with grouping :

```
'href=(.*)>'
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nE5kG7/1)

Or use a positive look-around :

```
'(?<=href=).*(?=>)'
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nE5kG7/2)

Comment: please have a look to my edit, I think your regex is perfect, but how can I make a regex on a List ? my app crash : java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence

Comment: @xcode_Dev You must not apply the regex on your array just the first index for example if your array is `CharSequence` you need to apply it on `CharSequence[0]`(if it just has 1 element), Also sorry that im not familiar with java!

Comment: Thanks for replying !  I edited my code, but I don't know how many objects is in my array : it's from JSON. But maybe I have to store List's values in String, and apply the regex on my string ?

Comment: @xcode_Dev If you want to store it as a string still the regex will work! but if you want to store as a list, you can loop over your list and check the regex for each element in each iteration!

Comment: Thanks! Last question : How can I loop over my list and check the regex for each element in each iteration ? :)

Comment: You can use a `for` loop then use a proper function for search a pattern with regex that you can find this function with searching about java regex function or ...! i think this is a simple task and as a lot of duplicate here in SO!

Comment: @xcode_Dev use the second regex!

Comment: Alright, (?<=href=).*(?=>) works !!!

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression is an option:

```
".*href='(.*)'.*"
```

Check example [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/cookbook/ahJzfnJlZ2V4cGxhbmV0LWhyZHNyDwsSBlJlY2lwZRjA1IwRDA/index.html). You can use

```
String str = "[<a rel=\"prettyPhoto[gallery-113]\" href='...";
str = str.replaceFirst(".*href='(.*)'.*", "$1");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=href=')[^']+(?=')
```

Use `lookarounds` for this.